# How To Restore Locked iPad Air 4th Gen. with Windows 10 and iTunes (2016/2020)

Tags: ipad

How can I restore my iPad with a Windows 10 machine if I don't remember the password and the iPad is in locked state?

Basically, what are the clear steps to get me back on-track without going back to the Apple store? I have installed the latest iTunes on my Windows 10 machine and the iPad is not recognized, the restoration process cannot be initiated.

Comment: Is this about programming?

Comment: It is about restoring a platform that can be used for SW development.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate I just moved to Ask and will delete this post on Stackoverflow. Thank you again for guidance!

Comment: moved to: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425748/how-to-restore-locked-ipad-air-4th-gen-with-windows-10-and-itunes-2016-2020/425749#425749